# Bash to count columns and registers

Tags: bash

I am trying to get the number of columns in bash of a dataset (taking into account that it has a header) using the following code but I am not convinced. Do you have any other idea?

On the other hand, Could you help me to determine how can I get the type of data that each attribute is (integer, date, string...) and count how many registers are in the dataset taking into account that it has a header?

The header of my archive is: "A","B","C","D","F","G","H","I"

```
head -n1 data | awk '{print NF-1}'
```

Thank you

Comment: You'll have to give some more info or show a proper sample of the data. The fact that you're using head/awk makes one assume we're talking about data in plain text or perhaps a CSV. But you're also talking about getting datatype information (which doesn't exist in either of those).; Your `"A","B",...`-example leaves a lot out; i assume instead of letters there are column names/labels there; could those contain spaces for example? or how about commas within the quotes.

Comment: `awk -F, 'NR == 1 { print NF; exit }' data`?

Comment: @Shawn Thank you! Worked perfectly. Do you have any idea of how I can count the number of records in the dataset (not including the header) and determine what type of data each attribute is? I would appreciate it very much

Comment: @Raxi Yes! It is a flat file separated by commas. Correct, each of the letters is an attribute, I just tried to avoid putting an example of the dataset with that example.

Comment: Yea i understand, and that is fine of course. But it helps to have slightly more realistic fakes that at least hint at the sort of data in there. Splitting the fields on comma will break if there can be commas inside the quoted columnnames for example.

Comment: @Raxi No, fortunately there are no commas inside the quoted columns.

Comment: ahyea, Shawn's recommendation should work fine then.

Comment: As for counting the rows , again it depends on the specifics (is every line a record, are there empty lines in the file. If none of those apply you can use `wc -l` to get the line count from the file (and then minus 1 for the header) -- another alternative is simply iterating over the records in bash with a while loop

Comment: And as for datatypes, they dont exist in a plaintext/csv file, everything is a string. Just because a certain field only contains "144", doesnt mean it should be an int. If every record has a numeric string in the same column, then it becomes very likely, but still no guarantees.